# .Ogg vs. .mp3 for a mobile app?

Tags: audio, mobile, mp3, html5-audio, ogg

I'm building a mobile application for Android, Windows Phone, IOS, and BlackBerry.

Its an audio application and I'm wondering if I should use ogg or mp3?

Ogg seems more compressed which is a good thing, but I'm not sure which of the 4 platforms it would work on, also is the quality worse?

I don't need to use the same file format for all of the platforms so answer with the best choice for each of the 4 platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html) and [Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) cannot play OGG audio files on their own, unless you are willing to write a decoder yourself (which you cannot do on Windows Phone 7 because you don't have raw access to the audio hardware).

[BlackBerry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18349/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf) does support OGG out of the box starting with v5 of BlackBerry OS.

[Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) lists it as a supported codec, however due to the open source nature of Android, it is entirely possible for a carrier to ship a product without the codec (I don't know if this has been done in practice).

However, all of those platforms can play MP3 out of the box. You are best off using MP3 for its ubiquity.

You may be able to achieve OGG-like sizes of your MP3 if you use a variable bitrate instead of a constant one.